# how to make async html parser in nodejs with promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

having fun with promises in JS and trying to craft simple xpath website parser, but I am struggling with logic on finishing overall parsing process, my code is:

```
var request = require('request');
var xpath = require('xpath');
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

var olxMain = 'https://www.some.site/';

var xpathRoot = '//a[contains(@href, "https://www.some.site/mask/")]';
var linksXpath = '//a';

var allGlobalLinks = [];


var getLink = function (node) {
    for (key in node['attributes']) {
        if (node['attributes'][key]['name'] === 'href') {
            return node['attributes'][key]['value'];
        }
    }
}


var getData = function (url, xpathPattern) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            console.log("Opening " + url);
            var processResponse = function (error, response, body) {
                var doc = new dom().parseFromString(body);
                var childNodes = xpath.select(xpathPattern, doc);
                var links = childNodes.map(function (n) {
                    return getLink(n);
                });
                resolve(links);
            };
            request({url: url}, processResponse);
        }
    );
}


var arrayUnique = function (x, i, a) {
    return a.indexOf(x) == i;
};

var main = function () {
    getData(olxMain, xpathRoot).then(function (links) {
        links = links.filter(arrayUnique);
        var maxThreads = 10, n = 0;
        var chunks = [];
        for (k in links) {
            var url = links[k];
            n++;
            if (n <= maxThreads)
                chunks.push(url);
            else {
                n = 0;
                // console.log(chunks);
                Promise.all(chunks.map(function (url) {
                    return getData(url, linksXpath);
                })).then(function (links) {
                    // add these links to global scope list here
                    });
                    console.log("Finished mappings iteration");
                });

                chunks = [];
            }
        }
        ;
    });
}




main();
```

So what I want is basically some kind of  `threadPool` with promises, how to I manage these 10 promises, when they all are finished, I should spawn another 10 more, until list is finished and all Promises have finished ?

Comment: *"how to make multithread html parser in nodejs with promises?"* You don't. NodeJS runs only a single thread. Promises don't, and can't, change that.

Comment: The body of your question isn't clear. What specifically are you struggling with? "...logic on finishing overall parsing process" is quite vague.

Comment: Don't see any error handling for you call to `request()`.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I see that maybe nodejs is wrong tool but decided to make trivial task in it. But how should I make requests parallel then ?  Python has GIL as well but some stuff with gevent and theading are allow to achieve some kind of parallelism, so I tried to implement parser in this way in node. I need to determine that all threads are finished, maybe should i wrap main in promise too ?

Comment: jfriend00, can this (absence of error handling) break execution of all promises in `all`?

Comment: psst!! use RegExp !